# Why didn't Nagini sense Harry at the shrieking shack?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

Probably another plot-hole? They were pretty close, given that they could hear Voldemort and Snape talk. Nagini sensed Harry (and maybe the Slytherin locket) when they were in Godric's Hollow from a range of... well a whole town. Even if she was strolling around the town disguised as Bathilda Bagshot she sensed Harry under the cloak and disguised by the polyjuice potion. The reason behind it is probably because Horcruxes can feel that they are close to each other (as the locket for example knew that it was near the snake).

So why didn't Nagini feel that Harry was close? I don't believe the protective cage would have to do anything with it because there is no reason to make it so that it blocks this. Voldemort knows that Nagini can find Harry even disguised or invisible since she had done it again so he would use it for his benefit.

Comment: Yes! I don't even remember what happens in the movies. I didn't like most of them

Comment: Anything else you'd like me to clarify in my answer?

Comment: No... I think the third part of your answer is the most probable.

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to accept it. :-)

Comment: @ApostolisKennedy I was going to up vote your comment but then I saw it wasn't all of them' but rather 'most of them'.... But actually it's not (as the other answer says) relevant the Invisibility Cloak. Snakes don't sense that way. Rowling actually points this out in an Q/A thing I think but it's definitely not a plot hole here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We know that she couldn't see them due to the Cloak, but snakes have other senses other than sight. Snakes can sense the vibrations on the ground made by their prey's movements, have infrared sensors that detect body heat and an acute sense of smell. Nagini couldn't sense this. Why?

#### **She was floating above the ground.**

> The room beyond was dimly lit, but he could see Nagini, swirling and coiling like a serpent underwater, safe in her enchanted, starry sphere, **which floated unsupported in mid-air**.

Hence she doesn't feel the vibrations made by their movements - because she wasn't on the ground.

#### **The sphere is the reason Nagini didn't sense them using her infrared detectors and sense of smell.**

This is the tricky and speculative part. One can only assume that Nagini's enchanted cage also "dulled" her senses. The cage served to "protect" Nagini from outside attacks, it may have served to "prevent" Nagini from smelling or sensing others while inside the cage. Here's a description of the sphere:

> "It is the only way, Nagini," he whispered, and he looked round, and there was the great, thick snake, now suspended in mid-air, twisting gracefully within the enchanted, **protected space** he had made for her, a starry, transparent sphere somewhere between glittering cage and tank.

Also, with Voldemort and Snape being in the same room, she might not have been able to differentiate their smell and the Trio's.

#### **Nagini's emotions were clouded by Voldemort's.**

Answered excellently [in this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146413/could-nagini-read-voldemorts-mind) which states that Nagini could sense Voldemort's emotions. As such, Voldemort's control state of fury and anger at Snape affected Nagini as well, and thus she too was focusing only on Snape, and didn't discern the Trio who were there.

> Voldemort's tone was musing, calm, but Harry's scar had begun to throb and pulse: pain was building in his forehead and he could feel that **controlled sense of fury building inside Voldemort**.

> **The stab of rage** felt like a spike driven through Harry's head: he forced his own fist into his mouth to stop himself from crying out in pain.

Nagini felt these emotions too, and hence was too preoccupied in being "angry" with Snape to notice that the Trio were present.

---

So what's the big diff. between the events of Godric's Hollow and the Shrieking Shack?

**In the Shrieking Shack, Nagini was just too preoccupied to notice the Trio, whereas in Godric's Hollow, she could focus all her attention on studying ("smelling") Harry and Hermione.**

Comment: The third makes sense.. The other 2 are not what I asked at all, because at Godric's she didn't use smell or anything else to find them. They had taken the polyjuice potion, so they didn't smell like themselves

Comment: I actually based my answer on the main question, not on your example on the Godric's Hollow incident. I'll edit my answer if you like.

Comment: Actually, @ApostolisKennedy your "secondary" question is answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116547/how-could-nagini-seem-to-see-harry-and-hermione-through-the-invisibility-cloak-w).

Comment: In Godric's hollow, Harry and Hermione were fooled by Nagini's disguise and reacted, so she did not to rely on any senses, but wisdom

Comment: what is this "Trio" that you keep mentioning? surely you don't mean Harry, Ron, and Hermione because only Harry was present for Snape's death.

Comment: @TBear I at least remember Hermione being with him. She created a bottle for him to put Snape's memories inside.

Comment: @ApostolisKennedy ah, I think you are right about Hermione.

Comment: @Voronwe well they had taken the polyjuice potion too. I believe the reason that Nagini found them in Godric's Hollow, was that she can sense a horcrux being near.. Just as the locket did. I'm talking about the link you shared. But I think you are right about Voldemort's emotions overpowering the sense of Harry.

Comment: Your idea about her not sensing them because she was airborne is certainly clever - but I'm not sure it fits with the events of Godric's Hollow. She couldn't have sensed them through ground contact then because she was walking around in the body of Bathilda Bagshot.

Comment: @TheDarkLord certainly, but remember: snakes have other senses other than that. The part on Godric's Hollow are all answered in the link I provided above

Comment: Do you have a reference for the assertion that Polyjuice Potion changes the way a person smells?  Anyway, it seems to me that the fact that she could smell someone, and hear footsteps, but not *see* anyone seems like it would be enough of a giveaway ...

Comment: No, I don't think there is one @HarryJohnston

Comment: @Harry Johnston well if the could change your sex, your vision, your height etc, it would change your smell too. I mean it completely transforms someone, to another person. The problem is if snakes use heat vision and smell she wouldn't know that it was them.. First of all she wouldn't even know that they were under invisibility cloak and second she would not know it was them

Comment: You seem to be assuming that snakes see only in the infrared.  My [quick research](http://animalworld.tumblr.com/post/2104315860/snake-eyes-how-snakes-see-by-mrclean1982) suggests that this isn't true.  So even if Nagini has infra-red vision and even if the Cloak doesn't hide your heat and even if Polyjuice Potion changes your smell, Nagini would *still* have been able to tell it was them, because they were under an invisibility cloak.  (A person you can see only in the infrared and not in the rest of the spectrum would look *really weird*.)

Comment: @ApostolisKennedy Ron was there too. Harry at first had the thought of not taking them but he was rather forced with all the dangers round them. They also ran into Dementors and even Harry could not summon the a Patronus - until three of the DA members did their own. There also was the funny mirroring of Hermione/Ron; in PS Ron asked Hermione if she was a witch or not (with the lights for the Devil's Snare I think it was); at the Whomping Willow Ron suggested it'd be useful to have Crookshanks; Hermione asked him if he was a wizard or not.

Comment: As for the last thought on the answer remember also that at Godric's Hollow Nagini was sent there because Voldemort was expecting Harry to go there; it was a planned ambush. Too much indeed was going on but I don't think she was meant to sense him either. Voldemort thought moments before that Harry was letting his friends die for him. Remember how he magically increases the volume of his voice only to tell them all he would be withdrawing his forces but if Harry does not come soon he'll go in personally. Then he shames Harry for letting his friends die for him. Just goading of course but...